# Why do we feel sad when feeling sad is bad?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

Everyone in the world feels sad. I also feel sad but I cannot understand the function and cause of this feeling. Can anyone tell me? Like, when someone scolds me, even if he is scolding me for some good reason, I feel sad. Why?

Comment: "....scolding for some good cause"... Perhaps the world's problems seem overwhelming to young people and they get sad. Try to have a physical goal every day, something you do with your hands. Organize one of your drawers, throw out some old stuff, clean something, whatever. Working on small problems with your hands  is the first step to working on larger problems. Also try to have a small intellectual goal to fulfill each day. If you seem busy with your hands and your mind, people are less likely to scold you.

Comment: You say you think sadness is bad. It is a judgement. However people fall into sadness _before_ any judgement about it. They become sad for some period because they find meaning being sad, and that meaning arises and is apprehanded before judgements can be made; not to say that it is completely unconscious, only that it is _precogital_ at nascending. And sadness is very much tied with the relation with _body_ at this stage.

Comment: "This being human is a guest house.
Every morning a new arrival.

A joy, a depression, a meanness,
some momentary awareness comes
as an unexpected visitor.

Welcome and entertain them all!
Even if they are a crowd of sorrows,
who violently sweep your house
empty of its furniture,
still, treat each guest honorably.
He may be clearing you out
for some new delight.

The dark thought, the shame, the malice,
meet them at the door laughing,
and invite them in.

Be grateful for whoever comes,
because each has been sent
as a guide from beyond." - Rumi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> feeling sad is not good i think

Feeling sad is **not a bad thing** always.  Almost all of us can give so many instances for this.  Often, solutions to many **problems** are found because of sadness.  Sometimes this sadness with slight variations becomes sympathy or empathy and this leads to many good activities/inventions.

We often listens only to what our senses bring to us. Sadness sometimes becomes a cause to find out the thing/world within us. Sometimes you might have already got instances for this from your/somebody's life.  You know that Arjuna was in distress and overwhelmed with grief on the battlefield.  You can read this in the first chapter of the Bhagavad Gita -- "Arjuna Vishada Yogam".  The questions he asked to Krishna (and the thing he could realize also) was about the greatest secrets of life.

> i cannot understand the reason to feel sad. can anyone tell me?

Often you feel sad because you have many desires to be fulfilled.  Uneasiness of your body or mind can also make you sad.

If you don't know the truth fully, it would also make you sad.  Sometimes knowledge of the truth would be the villain.  Fear of something would also make you sad. (All these are also a part of uneasiness of one's mind.) But the 'knowledge' of **the Ultimate Truth** or **strong faith** in God rubs off sadness.

> when someone scolds me even if he is scolding for some good
> cause,i feel sad, why?

This is because you are not quite sure whether that is a good thing and also  that (good thing) would happen smoothly. Something that works against your ego would also make you sad. But this depends on your character. Otherwise the outcome would be in the form of rage.

Answer (score 2):

According to [some studies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depressive_realism#Evidence_for) depressed people estimate actual likelihood of outcomes better than people in more normal moods.

Starting from that observation, there is a theory that even outside of the systematic sadness of depression, proper temporary sadness suppresses a natural [excess in optimism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimism_bias) ordinarily found in humans and makes you more careful, more observant and more open to learning from your mistakes.  There are times when this is the right way to be.

According to this theory, since we evolved from animals and spend time as children, and those prior generations and previous versions of ourselves have difficulty adapting their thinking by logic, before we had logic to apply to social situations and language to share information about them, we needed a switch for turning on and off our natural excessive optimism, and sadness was that switch, which automatically responds to a variety of triggers.

Given the other symptoms of sadness, which seem wasteful and are hard to relate to this purpose, the mood may have originated for some other purpose, like inducing hibernation or promoting rest so that we don't waste energy when we need help but others are not available to take care of us.  But (again assuming this theory) this triggering of carefulness and openness to self-doubt long ago became its primary purpose.

No one can tell you why you, in particular are sad without a lot more information.  But you may want to take the theory seriously and search your environment for things or situations from which you are failing to learn some lesson.

Answer (score 1):

People who are sad may be sad for a reason; they might have lost their home or some other disaster might have happened; this is sadness that is anchored on a real life happening.

However, a melancholic disposition was one of the four classical personality types. They tend to be more realistic than optimistic people. Today, melancholia has been medicalised and called depression.

If someone is being scolded for good reason then being upset seems a reasonable response. If it's without good cause then being annoyed or irritated seems reasonable. Human beings are full of passions, we are emotional beings. A man or woman or child who expresses no emotions, who is affectless would be seen as strange and alien; we express our emotions, and so daily we express both joy and sadness, happiness and unhappiness. It's what makes us human. We commiserate or celebrate.

Answer (score 0):

Feeling sad is not "bad" *per se*. That is a misunderstanding.

Pain is not something we enjoy, but it is necessary to prevent damaging the body (physical dimension). It can't be said that pain is "bad". Feeling pain causes a reaction intended to protect the body.

Sadness is the equivalent, but for the emotional dimension: feeling sad causes a reaction intended to improve the emotional self.

The main difference between pain and sadness is the complexity of the reactive process. Pain can be said to produce a simple reaction. If I feel pain because my finger is burning, I just move it away. Likewise, if I feel sad because my wife treats me bad, I will tend to get away from such situation, to improve my emotional state. Sadness is the negative indicator which produces the repelling reaction.

If I feel sad because someone died, my brain is telling me that the lack of that person is something negative. So, I should try to improve the situation.

In the first case, a divorce is the solution, and that could ease my sadness quite fast. But in the second case, the solution is not that simple. Sadness could last.